# How to decrease Query Time - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

PostgreSQL 9.6.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

I have a question about query time. This 'view' has +1M data and when you execute select*from view , its query time is +400 seconds. On my query, it returns 10k data and query time is around 8-10 seconds. I am looking for a way to decrease it to 1 or 2 seconds. I tried changing or deleting things in my where or select clause, but only solution i came up with is limiting between "time" part.

If anyone know a better solution, that would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Can

Note: This view contains three different tables(cl_segments,cl_participants,cl_party_info).
I could not find a definition for those tables but i will add pictures of indexes and fields. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

[clparticipantfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GSPq.png)

[clparticipantindexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ss5.png)

[clpartyinfofields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1mim.png)

[clpartyinfoindexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6rgf.png)

[clsegmentsfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY9MD.png)

[clsegmentsindexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOmd6.png)

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et4Gt.png)

```
select distinct on (clsgview.call_id)clsgview.call_id as call_id,
case when clsgview.src_dn_type = '0' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = '0' then
right(clsgview.src_dn,11)
when clsgview.src_dn_type = '1' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = '0' then
right(clsgview.src_caller_number,11)
when clsgview.src_dn_type = '0' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = ANY (ARRAY[1,12,13]) then 
right(clsgview.src_dn,11) end as from,
case when clsgview.src_dn_type = '0' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = '0' then
right(clsgview.dst_dn,11)
when clsgview.src_dn_type = '1' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = '0' then
right(clsgview.dst_dn,11)
when clsgview.src_dn_type = '0' and clsgview.dst_dn_type = ANY (ARRAY[1,12,13]) then
right(clsgview.dst_display_name,11) end as to,
case when clsgview.act = ANY (ARRAY[5,6]) and clsgview.dst_dn_type != ANY (ARRAY[12]) then (end_time-start_time) else '00:00:00' end as talktime

from 
( SELECT s.call_id,
    s.id AS seg_id,
    s.type AS seg_type,
    s.seq_order AS seg_order,
    s.start_time,
    s.end_time,
    si.dn_type AS src_dn_type,
    si.dn AS src_dn,
    si.display_name AS src_display_name,
    si.firstlastname AS src_firstlastname,
        si.caller_number AS src_caller_number,
    dp.start_time AS dst_start_time,
    dp.answer_time AS dst_answer_time,
    dp.end_time AS dst_end_time,
    dp.billing_rate AS dst_billing_rate,
    di.dn_type AS dst_dn_type,
    di.dn AS dst_dn,
    di.display_name AS dst_display_name,
    di.firstlastname AS dst_firstlastname,
    di.caller_number AS dst_caller_number,
    di.dn_class AS dst_dn_class,
    s.action_id AS act,
    ai.dn_type AS act_dn_type,
    ai.dn AS act_dn,
    ai.display_name AS act_display_name,
    ai.firstlastname AS act_firstlastname
   FROM ((((((cl_segments s
     JOIN cl_participants sp ON ((sp.id = s.src_part_id)))
     JOIN cl_participants dp ON ((dp.id = s.dst_part_id)))
     JOIN cl_party_info si ON ((si.id = sp.info_id)))
     JOIN cl_party_info di ON ((di.id = dp.info_id)))
     LEFT JOIN cl_participants ap ON ((ap.id = s.action_party_id)))
     LEFT JOIN cl_party_info ai ON ((ai.id = ap.info_id)))
         order by seg_id desc
) as clsgview
where clsgview.src_dn_type = ANY (ARRAY[0,1]) 
and clsgview.dst_dn_type = ANY (ARRAY[0,1,12,13]) 
and clsgview.act != ANY (ARRAY[1]) and ((clsgview.act = ANY (ARRAY[15,101,102,103,107,400,409,418,419,421,423])) or (clsgview.act = ANY (ARRAY[5,6]) and clsgview.dst_dn_type = ANY (ARRAY[12])))
and clsgview.dst_display_name not like '*%' and clsgview.dst_caller_number not like '*%'
and (clsgview.src_dn = '1004' or clsgview.dst_dn = '1004')  
and start_time::date BETWEEN '2020-01-01'::DATE and now()::DATE  
order by clsgview.call_id desc
```

Comment: It is going to be terribly hard for anyone to analyse such a large query. It is better to break it down to smaller queries and share the here to get answers faster.

Comment: Please add the execution plan as **formatted text** not as a (hard to read) screen shot. **[Edit]** your question, then paste the text of the plan put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Alternatively upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com/. The table definitions are also better shown as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: In addition to showing the EXPLAIN plan as text rather than (or in addition to) an image, you should also turn track_io_timing on, and increase work_mem by at least 16 fold, before taking the new plan.